# App to use with geotagged photos? (GPS info in EXIF)

Tags: photo-management, gps

Dad got a camera with built in GPS. The GPS info is embeded in the EXIF data, I guess. Picasa 3 puts a small "icon" on each of the geotagged photos, but can not do anything with them (as far as I can tell).

Is there any photo manager or mapping tool that can put these pictures on a map and/or let him browse trough the photos based on location?

Comment: +1 I think geotagged photos is a very exciting idea and would like to know how Ubuntu could handle such photos

Answer (score 9):

[Digikam](http://www.digikam.org/) is by far the **best photo-management utility on Linux**, and it does support [showing a map with your photos on it](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/extragear-graphics/digikam/using-digikam.html#using-mainwindow-mapview).

[image]

See this related page for [instructions on installing Digikam on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461140/how-to-install-digikam-on-ubuntu-14-04).

Comment: digikam is always ticking me off... first of all, when i install from a package geolocation support doesn't exist. i read somewhere that i have to manually install "kipi-plugins" - uh WHAT?! why isn't that a dependency already!? but it wants to install 302 unrelated packages including dolphin, etc... WHY? that is NOT happening, iit's ridiculous.  I found an appimage that has geolocation support, but there are no streets, nothing beyond county level resolution, when i just need to adjust a picture between my front and back yard, and this doesn't provide ANYWHERE near enough resolution!

Comment: @Michael: You're not wrong. I use KDE so I've already got most of the dependencies installed, but for users of other desktops it could be an issue.

Comment: Can't zoom the digikam map enough for sufficient precision. No use.

Answer (score 5):

[GpsPrune](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/GpsPrune) can plot your local photographs on a map, modify the data and export it in KML and other formats for use with mapping services like Google Maps or [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/).

`sudo apt-get install gpsprune`

Comment: GpsPrune is really performant and can scan a huge number of pictures quickly, then showing OSM tiles. All very nice - but as it seems not exactly designed for this purpose, it's not possible to rectangle-select a region and sift through the photos taken there.. #sad

Answer (score 4):

You want [GottenGeography](https://launchpad.net/gottengeography). It will show the locations of your photos on an OpenStreetMap background. It also will allow you to map photos from cameras without a built-in GPS, either by manual positioning on the map, or correlating with a GPS output file based on timestamp.

Comment: I just installed it, the goal of this application seems to be *adding* coordinates to pictures that do not have any. It does not show pictures that already have GPS coordinates on the map. Also, it can only load selected pictures from a given folder, and it takes a long time to load all pictures (no cache I guess). The last .deb (May 2017) seems to be at https://code.launchpad.net/~robru/+recipe/gottengeography-daily

Comment: Thanks for the update—it's been a long time since I've used it. I have found it useful for viewing photos that already have GPS coordinates, but there may now be better applications for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

According to this old post the present Digikam may be able to do what you want; http://scribblesandsnaps.wordpress.com/2009/11/03/geotagging-photos-with-digikam/, according to this post the soon to be released Digikam 2.0 will have even more advanced Geotagging features with the Reverse Geotagging widget, http://www.digikam.org/drupal/node/532.

I would say give Digikam a try to see if it will work for you now or if you will have to wait for version 2.0. Digikam is a very powerful photo management application available in the repositories.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Geotag](http://geotag.sourceforge.net/) to do that. This is a Javatool to geotag Photos and see them on a GoogleMaps page.

It is not a photo manager, but it is easy to see your photos on a map.

Comment: I'm trying it right now and it show latitude and longitude of photos taken with my smartphone.

Answer (score 0):

Flickr handle geo tagged photos and is able to display them on a map.
This is a web application and you need to upload your photos (2gb / month with a free account)

Privacy is a taking seriously and you have to adjust geotag settings because they are disallow by default.

I know this is not the kind of application you are looking for but this can help, Flickr is an excellent service to manage, backup, share ... your photos. I personally use it to backup all my photos.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, but, yeah, that's not what I'm looking for. :)