# How to install Digikam on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, photo-management, digikam

It seems that [Digikam was removed from Ubuntu 14.04](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/trusty/universe/proposed/digikam). **Why was that?**

Considering that Digikam is [the only photo organizer which works with geo-tagged photos](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19162/app-to-use-with-geotagged-photos-gps-info-in-exif), what would be the best way to install Digikam in Ubuntu 14.04?

Note that trying to install or search for Digikam turns up nothing:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo aptitude search digikam
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Also, clicking the .deb from UbuntuUpdates opens the Ubuntu Software Center which states that the dependencies for Digikam cannot be satisfied.

Comment: The link you posted says it moved. Please check here: http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/trusty/universe/base/digikam

Comment: @chili555: Thank you, I have edited the question to add more information.

Comment: What does this tell us? sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install digikam

Comment: @chili555: I had run `apt-get update` before trying. The search returned nothing, as can be seen in the OP.

Comment: but it doesn't run stable anyways on 14.04, you have to fix it up first: http://scribblesandsnaps.com/2014/12/12/making-digikam-stable-on-ubuntu-14-04/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have your universe repos enabled?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and I can see it:

```
$ apt-cache show digikam | grep Filename
Filename: pool/universe/d/digikam/digikam_3.5.0-0ubuntu10_amd64.deb
```

Try enabling the Universe repositories:

```
$ software-properties-gtk
```

Then leave the "universe" repositories option checked

[image]

Click "Close" and allow the packages info to be updated.

Comment: Thank you. I am actually testing from a LiveCD and I now see that [LiveCDs do not have Universe enabled](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/livecd-rootfs/+bug/105511). Enabling Universe seems to resolve the issue. Thank you!

Comment: In the end I was unable to install Digikam while running the LiveCD due to memory constraints, but I do see that this is the proper way to do so in a hard-drive install. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

digiKam 4.0 is out! if you'd like, install or upgrade it from PPA (14.04 only):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:msylwester/digikam

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install digikam
```

PPA: https://launchpad.net/~msylwester/+archive/digikam

via: [this quick tip](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/05/digikam-4-stable-install-in-ubuntu-14-04/)